# Get the north pole , South Pole. using TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD or TYPE_GYROSCOPE

Tags: android

Actually i need to get the device current position. like device is in south-west corner or device is in north-west corner. just like compass. I do not have any idea how can i get this done. I think i need to use sensor with type TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD. Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To conclude your actual position the most accurate is to use GPS. (0,0) is for North pole.

To implement Compass you should use Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values

For rough estimation of the North/South you can use Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD.